# angular6 dynamic module loading from external sources

Tags: webpack, angular-routing, angular6, dynamic-loading

I have a user case where I need to load modules from external sources in my angular6 container application. These modules are again angular6 applications written by separate teams which generate bundles which will be loaded at run time by container application on user navigation.

I tried angular elements but these are more like widgets and handing internal routing in these widgets is troublesome to handle in the container application.

I have failed to load angular bundles in container application at run time since webpack does not allow this behavior.

Does anybody know how to do this, I am open to all kinds of solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, You can use lazy load module mechanism.